# How can I import python libraries with .pyx and .c files without installing on the computer?

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I am writing code for a number of other people, none of whom are particularly computer savvy. I installed python 2.7 for all of them, but I really do not want to have to install anything else.

To get around installing every library that I wanted to use, I've simply been including the library source code in the same folder as my project source code. Python automatically searches for the necessary files in the working directory, and all goes well.

The problem came when I tried to install pandas. Pandas is a library that includes .pyx and .c files that are compiled on install. I cannot just include these files in with my source code, because they are not in the proper form.

How can I either compile these on launch or pre-compile them for ease of transfer? (And the kicker, I need a solution that works cross platform--I work on Windows 7, my colleagues work on OSX.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't compile one version for different systems. You will have to create separated version for any system. "compile on lauch" needs compiler and other tools on user computer - so it can be more complicated then pre-compiled versions.

Comment: I'm ok with separate versions, but then I need to be able to compile a version for OSX on my windows machine. Is that possible?